# Append string to matching columns (with various data types) in the same Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am looking for a way to turn this set of data

```
 columns0    columns1 columns2   
 row1         bill    bill   
 row2         $0.00   $0.00      
 row3         Free    $1.25
 row4         $1.50   $1.25
```

into this ...

```
 columns0     columns2        columns3   
 row1         bill( match)    bill(match)   
 row2         $0.00(match)   $0.00(match)  
 row3         Free            $1.25    
 row4         $1.50           $1.25
```

when I use this df.loc[(df['columns1'] == df['columns2  ']), :] += ' (Match)'

```
 columns0          columns1         columns2   
 row1**(match)**   bill( match)    bill( match)   
 row2**(match)**   $0.00(match)   $0.00(match)  
 row3              Free            $1.25    
 row4              $1.50           $1.25
```

I am getting a match on the columns0 as well.I would only like "match" to be on only columns1 and columns2.

I need some way to match the similarity across rows or even columns to find the match.

If anyone has a better way to go about this then or has resources that could help me figure out this issue in python + pandas issue, please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.loc` accessor for this, assuming your data is stored as strings.

```
df.loc[df['columns1'] == df['columns2'], :] += ' (match)'
```

If your data is not stored as strings, you would have to convert them beforehand:

```
df.loc[:] = df.loc[:].astype(str)
```

Result:

```
           columns1       columns2
row1   bill (match)   bill (match)
row2  $0.00 (match)  $0.00 (match)
row3           Free          $1.25
row4          $1.50          $1.25
```

If you only wish to check index row1 for a match:

```
df.loc[(df['columns1'] == df['columns2']) & (df.index == 'row1'), :] += ' (match)'

#           columns1      columns2
# row1  bill (match)  bill (match)
# row2         $0.00         $0.00
# row3          Free         $1.25
# row4         $1.50         $1.25
```

**Update**: The solution *still* works when the index is promoted to a column. You just have to select columns to update:

```
df.loc[df['columns1'] == df['columns2'], ['columns1', 'columns2']] += ' (match)'

#   columns0       columns1       columns2
# 0     row1   bill (match)   bill (match)
# 1     row2  $0.00 (match)  $0.00 (match)
# 2     row3           Free          $1.25
# 3     row4          $1.50          $1.25
```

Comment: Thanks so much it worked ! just to add on to this. If there is there a way to only place the "match" on the row1 or just the columns?@jpp

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that better. I only want the match to say on the columns with --> df.loc[(df['columns1'] == df['columns2']), :] += ' (match)'. The match is showing up on the row 1 and row 2. Thanks for the quick reply.